# confusing "Upload failed" message in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, apk, code-signing, google-signin

I would like to add a new App to Google Play.
I have already some apps signed and published to google play. All with the same key.
Now with the new one I get the message :

```
 Upload failed

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing, you should sign your APK with a new key before you upload it.
```

In the console it looks like the following :

[image]

I am not sure if it has something to do with "Google Play App Signing" ?

Can someone help ?

In the step of creating the first release, there was an button called "Reuse signing key". Is that what I should have clicked, if I want to sign the app like my older ones ?

Comment: I think to enroll in Google Play App Signing, you need to create a new key may be!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Google Play App signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en-GB) Google Play signs the app for you. You should upload signed with a new key, called the upload key.

If you really want it signed with the same key as your other apps (I wouldn't recommend this) then you should opt-out of Google Play app signing for this app.

Comment: Thanks Nick. Do you have an explanation for why you would not recommend ? What is the disadvantage ? And what is meant with "Reuse signing key" ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, because developers make mistakes all the time with keys. They accidentally delete the files, lose the password, or have annoyed ex-employees compromise the key. If Google signs the app for you Google developer support can switch you to a new key of any of these happen. Also, if every app is signed with a different key, it is easy for you to transfer ownership of your app to another company if you decide to sell it in future,